# Put conditional htmlattributes kendo attribute with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, kendo-grid

It is the first time that I use Kendo and I am quite lost, in this case I have a grid in the form of a table and there are fields that I do not show with ClientTemplate and depending on whether the ServiceStatusId field returns 5 I have to cross out the text and if not, leave it as it is. But I try to put a conditional for the case of the style and it doesn't work for me. I have tried several ways and I can't find a way to make a conditional to evaluate that. If I put it this way it will let me, but I need to indicate the conditional

```
style = "text-decoration:line-through;"
```

And this is how I have it right now:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Faculty.Web.Models.Ces.MyTasksProgramFilterViewModel>
                 ()
                 .Name("program_session_services_grid")
                 .AutoBind(true)
                 .Columns(columns =>
                 {
                     columns.Select().Width(50)
                     .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid_SelectColumn" })
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid_SelectColumn" });
                     columns.Bound(c => c.ProviderLiteral).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Assignment_Courses_Grid_Item_Center FontSize10 ", style = $"\\# if (ServiceStatusId==5) {{ \\# '" + "text-decoration:line-through;" + "' \\# }} \\#" })
                                     .Title(Resources.Ces.MyTasksPrograms_Grid_Header_Provider)
                                     .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Assignment_Courses_Grid_Header_Center " });
```

Any suggestion, help or advice is good for me, I already tell you that I have never touched Kendo until now and I need to apply this conditional and I don't know how to do it so that it detects it correctly and works.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use a template in the `.HtmlAttributes`. There's a few different ways you can solve this.

Probably the best way is to apply a template on the content.

```cs
columns.Bound(c => c.ProviderLiteral).ClientTemplate($"#=GetKendoTemplate(data,'ProviderLiteralTemplate')#");
```

Where GetKendoTemplate is a javascript method

```js
function GetKendoTemplate(data, templateName) {
    var templateObj = $('#' + templateName).html();
    var template = kendo.template(templateObj);
    return template(data);
}
```

And ProviderLiteralTemplate is a kendo template

```html
<script id="ProviderLiteralTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div style="# (ServiceStatusId==5) ? 'text-decoration:line-through;' : ''">
        <span>#=ProviderLiteral#</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but is there another way? Because they tell me that you don't have to use a separate javascript function or modify the kendo by removing the rest of the elements that you tell me. Likewise, in the code it is made with C# code, there is nothing of javascript that I have seen.

Comment: The kendo ASP library is a wrapper to generate javascript, so all code is javascript really. The GetKendoTemplate is just a helper method, otherwise you will be copying and pasting similar code throughout your application. You can use an inline template, but again, probably copying and pasting the same code multiple times. This is just an example, add or remove whatever column properties you need for your use case; I removed things that weren't relevant for this reply.